# The limit as $x$ goes to zero of $(1/x) -(1/\tan x)$ using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits, derivatives

I'm having trouble finding
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\biggl(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\tan x}\biggr)
$$

As $x$ approaches zero, the function is in indeterminate form, so I used L'Hôpital's rule and took the derivative: 
$$-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan^2x}
$$

This is still in indeterminate form and I still can't take the limit as x approaches zero, so I took the derivative again and still got it in indeterminate form. Is there something that I'm doing wrong either algebraically or with respect to differentiation?

Comment: You're differentiating the wrong things. Have a look again at what L'Hospital's rule says. You should be dealing with a limit of a *single fraction* in indeterminate form, and differentiate the *top and the bottom separately*

Comment: So differentiate $(tanx-x)/xtanx)$ ?

Comment: Correct. See @DavidP's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @onamoonlessnight in the comments, L'Hopitals works for a ratio of functions both tending to $0$ or $\pm\infty$. First combine:

$$\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{\tan x} = \dfrac{\tan x - x}{x\tan x} \to \ \dfrac{0}{0}$$

Now use L'Hopital's Rule.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\tan x - x}{x\tan x} =_{L'H} \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\overbrace{\sec^2x-1}^{\tan^2 x}}{x\sec^2x + \tan x} =  \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{\dfrac{x}{\sin x} + \cos x} $$

Comment: Maybe you might use *directly* that the derivative of $\tan x$ is $1+\tan^2x$?

Comment: Since that is not a typical "formula" for a "Calc I" student, it might not have been clear

Comment: I beg your pardon? This is a high school formula!

Comment: I believe Larson and Stewart are the most used texts in the US, so when possible, I default to their common definitions, methods, formulas, etc

Comment: This answer was great for my level of understanding :)

Comment: I was not reproching whatever, simply found strange such an elementary formula (it only requires *Pythagoras' identity* $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ to be deduced from $\sec^2x$) was not considered as basic. But I'm not speaking from U.S.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical case where  *Taylor's formula* is much simpler than *L'Hospital's rule*: $\tan  x=x+\dfrac{x^3}3+o(x^3)$, whence

- $\tan x-x\sim_0\dfrac{x^3}3$,
- $x\tan x\sim_0 x^2$.
  Thus 
  $$\frac1x-\frac1{\tan x}=\frac{\tan x-x}{x\tan x}\sim_0\frac{x^3}{3x^2}=\frac x3\to 0. $$

Comment: We haven't covered Taylor's formula in class yet... I'm in first year calculus and we're working our way through Spivak's calculus edition 4.

Comment: Well, let's say it anticipates a little. I'm sure you'll see it soon.

Comment: yes it's coming up within the next few chapters...thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

L'Hôpital's theorem *doesn't* apply as you did: if you have an indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$, but you cannot compute the limit of the difference of the derivatives.

L'Hôpital's theorem only applies to forms $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ (well, also to some other case, but that's not really important). Only then you can try computing the limit of the *ratio* of the derivatives.

So you have to transform the $\infty-\infty$ form into something that's manageable as a ratio:
$$
\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\tan x}=\frac{\tan x-x}{x\tan x}
$$
is one of them. Before using l'Hôpital, you can observe your limit can be written as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\tan x}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2}
=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cos x}{\sin x}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2}
$$
where the first factor has limit $1$, so you just need to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2}
\overset{\mathrm{(H)}}{=}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+\tan^2 x-1}{2x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}\frac{\tan x}{2}=0
$$
Recall that
$$
\tan'x=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}=\sec^2x=1+\tan^2x
$$